# How to increase the blob size in Azure Virtual machine dynamically?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I currently have a requirement in which , when a virtual machine disk space is full i will have to increase the disk space via Azure Storage Managment API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though storage management API supports resizing page blobs (which is how VMs are stored) through **Set Blob Properties** operation but **don't do that because it messes up VHD completely**. If I understand correctly about a VHD, it has a 512 bytes footer which contains information about that VHD. The Set Properties operation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee691966.aspx) just adds bytes to the existing page blob thereby messing this 512 byte footer. Your option would be to create a larger VHD and transfer the contents of your existing VHD to the new VHD.

Comment: should it be a Put Blob (REST API) call on azure ?